# AWS API Gateway - Cannot use CA signed client certificate trusted by external HTTPS endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

In AWS API gateway service, while configuring integration request there is no way to specify certificates required by external HTTPS endpoint.

For example - My API gateway method connects to https://example.com/resource, and the end point (https://example.com) required client certificate to be presented to establish connection. So there is no way in AWS console to specify the certificates.

Comment: It's unclear what you're question is.  Please be specific and show examples of what is failing.

Comment: @kenlukas - I have updated the question.

Comment: Here is the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html what else is missing? or - do you want to import your own?

Comment: @gusto2 , Yes I want to import/use my own client side certificate. For that I already imported my client certificate to AWS using ACM but there is no way in API gateway console to use that as well.

Comment: Apparently not (at least I don't see the option) . Then you need to setup the backend to use a certificate generated by the API Gateway